# setOnClickListener is not working while setOnTouchListener is working in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, onclick, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I am making an meme maker application so i am allowing the user to add textviews to the image and drag the textview anywhere in the imageview. Initially all textviews are in 'GONE' visibility and when user clicks on 'Add text' button, i will make one textview visible at a time. I am able to drag and drop the textview anywhere i like but the onclicklistener is not working. I want to show the user that they clicked on the textview and give them options to edit the text like color,size etc. But the toast is never showing up, no errors as well.  The code for it is as follows:

```
class MemeActivity : AppCompatActivity(){


    var mLayoutRoot: RelativeLayout? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meme)
        tv1.setClickable(true);
        setSupportActionBar(meme_toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        meme_toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
        val intent=intent
        val memeImage=intent.getStringExtra("image")
        Picasso.get().load(memeImage).into(meme_image)

        mLayoutRoot=findViewById(R.id.rl_meme)

        val added=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_add_text)
        val save=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.save_meme)

        added.setOnClickListener {
            if(tv1.visibility==View.GONE){
                tv1.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }
            else if (tv2.visibility==View.GONE){
                tv2.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }
            else if (tv3.visibility==View.GONE){
                tv3.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"No More",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        tv1.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"clicked tv1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


        tv1.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv2)
        tv2.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv2)
        tv3.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListenerTv2)



    }





    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (!mLayoutRoot!!.isFocused) {
            mLayoutRoot!!.requestFocus()
            mLayoutRoot!!.requestFocusFromTouch()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


    val mOnTouchListenerTv2: View.OnTouchListener = object : View.OnTouchListener {
        var prevX = 0
        var prevY = 0
        override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            val par =
                v.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            when (event.action) {

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    par.topMargin += event.rawY.toInt() - prevY
                    prevY = event.rawY.toInt()
                    par.leftMargin += event.rawX.toInt() - prevX
                    prevX = event.rawX.toInt()
                    v.layoutParams = par
                    return true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    par.topMargin += event.rawY.toInt() - prevY
                    par.leftMargin += event.rawX.toInt() - prevX
                    v.layoutParams = par
                    return true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    prevX = event.rawX.toInt()
                    prevY = event.rawY.toInt()
                    par.bottomMargin = -2 * v.height
                    par.rightMargin = -2 * v.width
                    v.layoutParams = par
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

The XML code goes as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_meme"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MemeActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout_meme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/meme_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkGrey">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/app_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Meme"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/save_meme"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_save_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Meme" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_overall_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGrey"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout_meme">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_textsize"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:src="@drawable/textsize1"
                android:textColor="#6E6B6B"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_textcolor"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/textcolor"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_italic"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:src="@drawable/italic"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_bold"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                android:src="@drawable/bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_delete"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                android:src="@drawable/delete"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_meme_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="420dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/meme_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                android:tag="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                android:tag="2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                android:tag="3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/fl_meme_container"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:text="Add Text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fl_meme_container" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please help me how to make onClicklistener work?